# Randomize tor entering node

Tags: whonix

when I run whonix gateway it almost all time use same first node. When I restart tor it makes new circuit with different exit node but first node is still the same IP.

What's the way how TOR choose first node? It's the one with best latency?

I'd like to make it more random.

Thank You.

Comment: Tor is designed to use the same guard (entry node) for a period of time. This makes it harder for malicious guards to gather traffic. Either you're connecting to the same "safe" node every time, or your traffic is compromised every time. Rotating the guard every time increases your chance of picking a "bad" entry node.

Answer (score 0):

there's **no straight way** to control the entries, but:

- Using `EntryNodes` with `StrictNodes` can give you a hand here
- Using bridges - even controlled by you - will help you to diversify the link map